# How to close previous mdi child in parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, mdichild, mdiparent

I have a mdi parent `form` and I open my other `forms` in run time as mdi child form by this code:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    childform = new childform ();
    frm.MdiParent = Mdiparent;
    frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    frm.Show();
}
```

but the problem is: When current form is open, user can open another form and it can be repeated several times so that each form is opened
what's code for closing the current child form **before** user open a new child form??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

tanx for ur assist :)
I Found effective code by test other Members in Class Windows.forms
just enough check this :

```
if (ActiveMdiChild != null)
    ActiveMdiChild.Close();
```